# Why is adding a BorderBrush ignored?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I changed my hyperlink from this:

```
   <HyperlinkButton x:Name="hyperlinkButtonManageInvitations" Margin="24"
                    Grid.Row="1" Tap="HyperlinkButtonManageInvitations_OnTap">
       Manage Invitations
   </HyperlinkButton>
```

...to this:

```
    <HyperlinkButton x:Name="hyperlinkButtonManageInvitations"
                     BorderBrush="DarkOrange" Margin="24" Grid.Row="1"
                     Tap="HyperlinkButtonManageInvitations_OnTap">
        Manage Invitations
    </HyperlinkButton>
```

...and there was no visual change - no border was added. So I then tried tweaking some more properties like so:

```
    <HyperlinkButton x:Name="hyperlinkButtonManageInvitations"
                     BorderBrush="DarkOrange" Margin="24" Grid.Row="1"
                     Tap="HyperlinkButtonManageInvitations_OnTap"
                     BorderThickness="4" OpacityMask="Black">
        Manage Invitations
    </HyperlinkButton>
```

...and still no go. What part of adding a border am I not grokking?

### UPDATE

My hyperlinkbutton is now:

```
    <HyperlinkButton x:Name="hyperlinkButtonManageInvitations" Style="{StaticResource BorderedHyperlinkButtonStyle}" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Red" Foreground="DarkOrange" Margin="24" Grid.Row="1" Tap="HyperlinkButtonManageInvitations_OnTap" Content="Manage Invitations">
    </HyperlinkButton>
```

...and I added the style provided below to the  section of App.xaml, but I still see now border around the hyperlinkbutton in question.

### UPDATE 2

It's there now - it "suddenly" appeared; I guess the xaml renderer can be slow on the uptake now and then. Or when using a newly-added style, the project needs to be reloaded first, or...???

Comment: Try taking the `OpacityMask` property off.

Comment: Removing OpacityMask (returning it to its default value of "No Brush") makes no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's got to do with the HyperlinkButton control template; if you go to Blend and create a copy of the control template to edit, you'll get something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
  <Border Background="Transparent">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
      <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
          <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="TextElement"/>
          </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
          <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextElement">
              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
      </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneHorizontalMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
      <TextBlock x:Name="TextElement" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextDecorations="Underline" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
    </Border>
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

So you can check here that there is no TemplateBinding to the control BorderBrush and BorderThickness property.

To fix your issue, just copy this style and insert it in the page/app resources:

```
<Style x:Key="BorderedHyperlinkButtonStyle" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
        <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="TextElement"/>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextElement">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneHorizontalMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextElement" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextDecorations="Underline" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
          </Border>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then, on the HyperlinkButton you want with a Border, set it's like this:

```
<HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource BorderedHyperlinkButtonStyle}" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Red" />
```

Edit the BorderThickness and BorderBrush as you like!

Comment: Strange that adding BorderBrush doesn't work "out of the gate," as page 189 of Adam Nathan's "Windows 8 Apps with XAML and C#" indicates it does. The text *does* mention, speaking of HyperlinkButton: "Its default appearance differs from Button in that its border is invisible" but I don't see where/how I can set Border.Visibility explicitly to Visible.

Comment: The XAML above looks strange to me - is Border Background being set twice? If so, why?

Comment: I copy-and-pasted that code into my Hyperlink and prepended BorderBrush="DarkOrange" to <Border Background="Transparent"> so that it became <Border BorderBrush="DarkOrange" Background="Transparent"> and then BorderBrush="ForestGreen" to <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" so that it became <Border BorderBrush="ForestGreen" Background="{TemplateBindingBackground}" etc. but no border is added...

Comment: Why are you quoting a Windows 8 book when you are developing for Windows Phone 8? Do remember that there may be differences!! ;) I've edited my response to include the full HyperlinkButton Style with an altered Template.

Comment: I would think the xaml in Windows 8 and Windows Phone would be identical, or nearly so. I'm still waiting on a Windows Phone book - the nearest release that I'm aware of is not until May - one by Shawn Wildermuth.